# SQL grouping via timestamp produced unexpected results

Tags: mysql, sql

I am building an inventory management system and i'm currently working on the reporting functionality. I wish to query the sum of products sold each daybefore a given date. The query:

```
SELECT created_at as created_at, SUM(quantity) as product_sales
FROM sales_products
WHERE created_at > '2018-04-19'
GROUP BY created_at
ORDER BY created_at DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

And the output:

```
"created_at"    "product_sales"
"2018-05-01 09:41:51"   "110"
"2018-05-01 09:41:11"   "150"
"2018-05-01 09:40:57"   "120"
"2018-04-29 16:25:50"   "12"
"2018-04-25 11:54:26"   "2385"
"2018-04-24 11:54:26"   "2485"
"2018-04-23 11:54:26"   "2278"
"2018-04-22 11:54:26"   "2277"
"2018-04-21 11:54:26"   "2330"
"2018-04-20 11:54:26"   "2408"
"2018-04-19 11:54:26"   "2425"
```

Now up untill today that i inserted more values the sum took place the way i intended. But records with a slightly different timestamp are not grouped. I also tried using LEFT(created_at, 10) to select only the date part but it didn't work.

Any ideas?

Thank you very much in advance!

```
SELECT LEFT(created_at, 10) as created, SUM(quantity) as product_sales
FROM sales_products
WHERE created_at > '2018-04-19'
GROUP BY created_at
ORDER BY created_at DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

Comment: `group by date(created_at)` will solve that.

Comment: group by should be for other columns of select which not included for function. This case group by for  'created'

Comment: Same goes for `select`, you should use `date(created_at)` instead of `left(created_at,10)`

Comment: which data type is created _at column??

Comment: The data type is timestamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help:

```
select cast(created_at as date) as Day, sum(quantity) as product_sales 
from sales_products
where created_at > '2018-04-19'
group by Day
order by Day desc
limit 100
```

Comment: Yes! cast() did the trick!!  Thanks so much! if can bother you a bit more with a question, Should the field created_at be datetime instead of timestamp as a better practice?

Comment: As I am not completely aware of the environment, I would recommend you go through this article. It explains the difference really well. https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1215635/MySQL-DATETIME-vs-TIMESTAMP.

Comment: Ok will do! Thanks again, have a great day!

Comment: Glad I could help. In short, if you have systems in multiple time zones and you want each user to see data in accordance with their timezone use timestamp, else use DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

To group by the day, use `group by date(created_at)`:

```
select date(created_at) as day, sum(quantity) as product_sales 
from sales_products
where created_at > '2018-04-19'
group by day
order by day desc
limit 100
```

The [`date`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function extracts the day from the expression and discards the time of day, which could vary across your records.

Comment: It did not work :/ Produces an sql error 1055. I also tried casting the created_at as date in the select clause just in case

Comment: It seems date() did not cast it as intended although the mindset was the same! Thank you for your quick response and time!!

Comment: Nevermind. using date now also did the trick. I must have typed something wrong before!